# How to cut tibble with top% fraction?

Tags: r, dplyr

Take data `diamonds` as example (just for problem illustration, can't run):

```
brks <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)   # use fraction as breaks: every top 10%
labs <- seq(10, 100, 10) # name of each label: top%

diamonds %>% 
    group_by(color) %>%
    mutate(bin = cut(diamonds$price, breaks = brks, labels = labs))
```

I want to add a column to label each row as the top% price of each `color` group.

Base R function [cut](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/cut) does similar work, but `cut` need the specific breaks, but I want to label with top% price.

Comment: Maybe  you are looking for `quantile()` function. It'll help if you add the expected output to your post. Also, which package is `diamonds` from?

Comment: Can u specify the top% u want to use like : top 5%, top10% and so on..

Comment: Thank you Shree and Vikrant, for your quick response! eipi10's answer meets my need, thank you again!

Comment: Yes, @Vikrant, if I want to label 5%, 20%, and 50%, not equal space, there can be a better answer than ntile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark, say, the decile (ranked groups, each of which contains 10% of the values) within each level of `color`, you would do:

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds = diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color) %>%
  mutate(bin = ntile(price, n=10))
```

Summarise bins:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color, bin) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            mean_price = mean(price))
```

> ```
>    color bin    n mean_price
> 1      D   1  678   559.0310
> 2      D   2  677   736.2230
> 3      D   3  678   899.3142
> 4      D   4  677  1150.0842
> ...
> 57     I   7  542  5341.4004
> 58     I   8  542  7325.0886
> 59     I   9  542 10572.9207
> 60     I  10  542 15777.6697
> ```

If you want the bin labels to run from 10 to 100 in instead of 1 to 10, multiply the labels by 10:

```
  mutate(bin = 10 * ntile(price, n=10))
```

To answer the follow-up question in your comment, here's one option. We split the data by `color` so that we can `cut` by quantiles within each level of `color`.

```
diamonds = diamonds %>% 
  split(diamonds$color) %>% 
  map_df(~ .x %>% 
           mutate(price.bins.by.color = cut(price, breaks=quantile(price, probs=c(0, 0.05, 0.2, 0.5, 1)),
                                            labels=c("0%-5%", "5%-20%", "20%-50%", "50%-100%"), include.lowest=TRUE))
  )

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color, price.bins.by.color) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean_price=mean(price)) %>% 
  filter(price.bins.by.color=="20%-50%")
```

> ```
>   color price.bins.by.color     n mean_price
> 1 D     20%-50%              2021      1233.
> 2 E     20%-50%              2938      1167.
> 3 F     20%-50%              2848      1448.
> 4 G     20%-50%              3386      1372.
> 5 H     20%-50%              2487      1863.
> 6 I     20%-50%              1626      2163.
> 7 J     20%-50%               843      2749.
> ```

Comment: Hi @eipi10, if I want to label not equal spacely, say 5%, 20%, and 50%, then how to do that?